# How to display images to delete using PHP Unlink

Tags: php

I have a script that deletes images from a folder using PHP.

The problem is the images arenot being displayed on the page.

My code is as below

```
<?php
// directory separator
defined("DS")
    || define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// root path
defined("ROOT_PATH")
    || define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

// upload folder directory
defined("UPLOAD_DIR")
    || define("UPLOAD_DIR", "uploads");

// path to the upload folder
defined("UPLOAD_PATH")
    || define("UPLOAD_PATH", ROOT_PATH.DS.UPLOAD_DIR);


function getAllFiles($folder = null) {
    if(!empty($folder) && is_dir($folder)) {
        if($handle = opendir($folder)) {
            $out = array();
            while($file = readdir($handle)) {
                if(is_file($folder.DS.$file)) {
                    $out[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
            return $out;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

$files = getAllFiles(UPLOAD_PATH);

if (!empty($_POST['file'])) {
    foreach($_POST['file'] as $file) {
        unlink(UPLOAD_PATH.DS.$file) or die("Failed to <strong class='highlight'>delete</strong> file");
    }
    header("location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
?>

<?php if (!empty($files)) { ?>

<form name="form1" method="post">
    <?php foreach($files as $key => $file) { ?>
        <label for="file_<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <input type="checkbox" name="file[]" id="file_<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" /> 
            <?php echo $file; ?>
        </label>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

The code works fine to delete the images but does not display the images on the page.

Your help is much apprecited.

Thank You

Comment: I don't see any code to display any images in your script. Can you clarify what this is supposed to do?

Comment: +1 for your condition defines `defined("DS") || define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` as a nice way to do it, never thought of doing it that way

Comment: @Pekka +1, I'm wondering if it's not just a missing `<img src="<?php echo UPLOAD_DIR."/".$file; ?>"/>` in the form...

Comment: @RobertPitt - Joomla does it by default (FYI).

Comment: I fail to understand how a browser is supposed to load/show images which have been deleted on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think the images are still in the browser cache, so deleting the cache will result in not seeing any deleted images.